# Advantages of using Reactjs for form?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

I want to make a signup and login form.I do it with simple HTML,CSS & JS,But on internet I heard about Reactjs.I read that react is best over the simple html,css and js. So I want to know that is it Reactjs is best over simple forms. And what is the advantages of using reactjs for forms.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in react is built using components, you can split your form up into sections and use each section is a separate component, this way it's much easier to manage and you are able to create a more dynamic form.

HTML and CSS is fine if you just want a static form, but if you start introducing a lot of dynamic features it can start to get messy, if you know little about react i would suggest watching some youtube content as a video will be able to show you the benefits much better than someone explaining in a few paragraphs